# Python Code runs on desktop but not on cluster: UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-computing, python-unicode

I have done some research but could not find a related topic anywhere online, which is why I post the question here.

The problem is as follows: I wrote a Python3 code which runs perfectly on my MacBook but does not do the same on the cluster I am using. It always throws out a `UnicodeEncodeError` at exactly the same point as illustrated here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "B_main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import D_fuzzy_matching
  File "/home/firmdata/name/python/D_fuzzy_matching.py", line 105, in <module>
    df2[cols_to_keep].to_csv(folder4 + 'fuzzy_matches/' + item[:-1].lower() + '.txt', index=False, header=False)
  File "/home/firmdata/name/python/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1745, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "/home/firmdata/name/python/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 165, in save
    compression=self.compression)
  File "/home/firmdata/name/python/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 400, in _get_handle
    f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding)
```

The corresponding lines in my Python3 code are:

```
df2[cols_to_keep].to_csv(folder4 + 'fuzzy_matches/' + item[:-1].lower() + '.txt', index=False, header=False)
```

I already checked, pip on the cluster includes exactly the same libraries as pip on my local desktop. Moreover, the Python version I am using on my desktop is

```
Python 3.6.4
```

whereas on the cluster

```
Python 3.6.2
```

is available.

Another information I can give is that, in order to setup a working Python-environment for my need, I refer to virtual environments because otherwise I could not install libraries via pip.

I would highly appreciate if anyone could give me some hints about what exactly I am doing wrong :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the most simple of all, to generate all the UTF locales you may be using if the cluster is a *unix machine.

You can check which are currently enabled with:
    locale -a

To add more locales you can use:
    sudo locale-gen en_US
    sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF8
    sudo update-locale

Or in a more Ubuntu way:
    sudo apt-get install language-pack-(XX)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response. I have done what you recommended. As the character causing the problem is '\xfc', which relates to the 'ü' in the German language, I looked up the corresponding locals. On my computer they are labeled: 'de_AT de_AT.ISO8859-1 de_AT.ISO8859-15 de_AT.UTF-8 [...] de_DE.UTF-8'. On the cluster, which indeed is a unix machine, more or less the same locales (slightly different spelling though) are used (de_AT de_AT@euro de_AT.iso88591 de_AT.iso885915@euro [...] de_DE.utf8). Thus, it probably does not make too much sense to install further locales, what do you think?

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not a locales guru.
A change is change in the locales. It may also be the case that the locale *used* is what changes between the two machines. Try with the same locales and also check which one is used:
    locale
Take note that the LC_ALL= *** is what overwrites any other setting, so if it is set it means that this is used.